# How closely related do two Uchihas have to be in order for one to obtain the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan?

Tags: naruto

When a user of the [Mangekyō Sharingan](http://naruto.wikia.com/wiki/Mangeky%C5%8D_Sharingan) wants the Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan, do they *have* to take the eyes of their sibling, or could they obtain the EMS by taking the Sharingan eyes of any Uchiha?

[image]

While researching, I found this:

> Their vision can be restored by receiving the transplanted Mangekyō of
>   an Uchiha with strong blood ties — ideally a sibling — thus awakening
>   so-called Eternal Mangekyō Sharingan.

So my question is: what is considered "strong blood ties"? Father, aunt, 2nd cousin twice removed?

Is there any other source that explains this in greater detail?

Comment: Well, since it says "strong blood ties" I guess they do have to be closely related or else it won't work?

Comment: @Ms.Steel Yeah, so I'm asking what exactly does that mean? Let's say that Itachi had access to his father's eyes. If he transplanted those, would he obtain the EMS? I would consider a father to be a "strong blood tie", but they never mention anything like that in the show. All they mention is taking the eyes of their siblings.

Comment: Itachi will only activate the EMS if his father already had the MS, if he didn't then... to bad for him I guess.

Comment: @Ms.Steel, that's not true. Itachi was "attempting" to take Sasuke's eyes to obtain the EMS, and Sasuke did not have the Mangekyō Sharingan.

Comment: Then I have no idea, that was just my theory...

Comment: i thought the sharingan was activated or evolve when the uchiha felt a deep emotional trauma or something, so unless it a blood tie, one person doesnt feel that same intensity of emotional trauma. Could that be one of the reason ?

Comment: @HunterTurner Itachi lied about that. His goal wasn't to obtain an EMS for himself. His goal was to make Sasuke stronger. So your point is invalid.

Comment: I always thought that to get the EMS, you needed to have awakened the MS and get someone's Sharingan who had already awakened the MS too or else it won't work... That's my theory at least, but who knows maybe that's how it works?

Comment: @AyaseEri, he was hiding his true motives by pretending to go after Sasuke's eyes, but I believe that what he told Sasuke about the MS was true. For example, let's say you can only obtain the EMS from another "strong blood tie" MS. If Sasuke knew that before facing Itachi, then he would have know that Itachi was lying. Is it mentioned anywhere else that the eyes needed for the EMS have to be from a strong blood tie MS?

Comment: @Ms.Steel, do you have a source that you can point us to?

Comment: Maybe I should create another question asking if the EMS requires another MS, because that's what this conversation is leaning towards.

Comment: Like I said, it's just my theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer to this question is that there is not enough evidence to answer this question correctly without any speculation.

Throughout the series, Uchiha Madara and Uchiha Sasuke are the only ones to obtain Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan. Both obtained it by transplanting their brothers' eyes and both of their brothers have obtained Mangekyou Sharingan before the transplatation happened. Thus, we can't say for sure whether transplanting other close relatives eyes would work or not.

Genetically speaking, a child is genetically 50% of his mother and 50% of his father. Him and his sibling can be more similar in case of a identical twin. But most of the time, they would be genetically more distant. A child would most likely have a different sets of chromosome compared to his sibling. Because of this, the genetic similarity between siblings vary.

If we are to take Madara and Sasuke's case as the base for our hypothesis, then transplantation between a child and his parents should work. Transplanting from grandparents should also work since they are 25% genetically similar. Transplanting from Aunt or Uncle might work, depending on how similar they are to the recipient genetically. The further away they are genetically, the less chance for it to work. That is if we take that Eternal Mangekyou Sharingan requires Mangekyou Sharingan from a close relative.

Comment: One question I do have. When Itachi "gave" Sasuke the Mangekyō Sharingan, did he lose it himself? If so, then saying "_both of their brothers has obtained Mangekyou Sharingan before the transplatation happened_" would not be true, because it would have been already transferred to Sasuke and Itachi would not have the MS. It's hard to say if this happened or not, because he died right after.

Comment: Sasuke's eye transplantation happened after his fight against Danzo, which is quite some time after Itachi's death. Transplantation means he takes Itachi's eyes and put it into his own eye socket. This is more evident in Madara's case where his brother was shown dead with cloth covering his eyes, suggesting that his eyes was taken.

Comment: I felt as if this question was turning into a different one (partly my fault), so I created [this new question](http://anime.stackexchange.com/questions/36974/are-strong-blood-tie-mangeky%C5%8D-sharingan-eyes-required-for-the-eternal-mangeky%C5%8D) talking about if a normal Sharingan can be used for EMS.